# Changing content of the label with checkbox and CSS, w/o JavaScript

Tags: html, css, sass, label, themes

I would like to achieve changing the content for `label` when the checkbox is checked and vice-versa.

For that I prepare the following implementation:

I paste the invisible checkbox directly after `<body>`:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="theme-switch" />
```

with the SASS:

```
input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]
    display: none
    &:not(:checked)
        & ~ label[for=theme-switch]
            & > .sun
                &::before
                    content: var(--theme-moon)
    &:checked
        & ~ label[for=theme-switch]
            & > .sun
                &::before
                    content: var(--theme-sun)
```

And the result element can be placed anywhere in the body with the following content:

```
<label for="theme-switch">
    <div class="sun"></div>
</label>
```

Obviously, I want to replace the content of the `.sun` with text valid for that state.

I am not putting the checkbox nearby the label, because I am controlling the theme with it.

The following Sass code is designed for it:

```
# Some cycle
@if $theme == dark
        \:root[data-theme=#{$theme}], html:has(> body > input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]:checked), body:has(> input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]:checked), input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]:checked ~ header, input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]:checked ~ main, input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]:checked ~ article, input#theme-switch[type=checkbox]:checked ~ footer
            @include theme($theme)
```

Is there any way to change the `content` of `label` only with CSS (SASS) and w/o JavaScript? Or is there any other trick to achieve it?

Comment: `~` is the general sibling combinator. So `input:checked ~ label` would only select the label, if it was an actual sibling of the input field - which with your _"can be placed anywhere in the body"_ probably isn't the case. You will need to target an actual sibling of the input, then you can target the label within that.

Comment: I can restructure it to put it in a certain region of the page. But can it be achieved w/o JavaScript? Let's imagine putting it in: `header > nav > .navbar-menu > div > div > label` input and header are on the same level in HTML.

Comment: Then it would be `input:checked ~ header > nav > .navbar-menu > div > div > label`.

Comment: Working! I can promote your answer as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is the general sibling combinator. So `input:checked ~ label` would only select the label, if it was an actual sibling of the input field. You will need to target an actual sibling of the input, then you can target the label within that.

> Let's imagine putting it in: `header > nav > .navbar-menu > div > div > label` input and header are on the same level in HTML.

Then it would be `input:checked ~ header > nav > .navbar-menu > div > div > label`.

The important thing is to target the actual sibling first, otherwise `~` won't work. After that, you can select anything you want *inside* `header`.